# How to put a USB keyboard into suspend mode on Ubuntu without suspending the system?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, usb, suspend

I'm trying to figure out how to put a USB keyboard into suspend mode without suspending the entire system.

I have a Corsair K95 keyboard with backlighting, and I want to power it down when the system is idle, but want the system to stay awake and run assorted background tasks. I'm assuming the keyboard will wake from suspend when a key is pressed (if not, how do you wake it?)

Is it done through an IOCTL to one of the devices associated with the keyboard?

If I can figure out how to control the keyboard, I can manage tying it to the screen's sleep behavior.

Edit:

Further research shows this should be the answer, but I can't get it to actually work:

Locate the device under /sys/bus/usb/XXX (lsusb -v helped) and as root:

```
echo auto > <device_dir>/power/control
echo 0 > <device_dir>/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

However, I can't get this to work for the keyboard I want to control.

Answer (score 0):

More digging has shown two problems.

A) There are multiple devices in /sys/bus/usb/XXX for the keyboard. Power control is ignored for all devices except for the top level node.

B) It still doesn't work for the Corsair K95, but does work with a Ducky Shine 3. I have no idea why.